# Using the Checkbox in a void

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a void that will accept 2 classes. One of String and the other I was hoping to put the name of a check-box object in there.

what I am trying to achieve is this void will go into the registry and check if the "suggested" key exists. if it does then to check the appropriate box, if not then leave the box unchecked.this is what I have so far:

where I am stuck is in the if statement, it's not giving me an option of checkbox.checked. How can I check the box?

```
public static void regcheck(string valuename, object checkbox)
    {
        string keyName = @"Software\softwarename";
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
        {
            if (key.GetValue(valuename)==null)
            {
                checkbox.
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using a CheckBox as the parameter `regcheck(string valuename, CheckBox checkbox) as `object` is not a `CheckBox` without casting
`

Comment: You are taking in checkbox as object.  The object class doesn't know anything about "Checked", because it can be anything.  Cast it to a CheckBox or change the parameter from object to CheckBox to get a Checked property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to cast the `object` as `CheckBox` if you want to access `CheckBox` properties

```
if (key.GetValue(valuename)==null)
{
    (checkbox as CheckBox).IsChecked = true;
}
```

or change your parameter to `CheckBox`

```
public static void regcheck(string valuename, CheckBox checkbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, look for a property call "IsChecked" it has a type of bool? (nullable bool)